# Add function argument validation for optional parameters based on the values of required parameters

Tags: matlab

I have a function signature like this:

```
function MyFunc(a, b, options)
%% Function argument validation
arguments
    %% @Required parameters:
    a (1,1) {mustBeInteger, mustBePositive}
    b (1,1) {mustBeInteger, mustBePositive}
    %% @Optional parameters:
    options.n_bar (1,1) {mustBeInteger, mustBeLessThanOrEqual(options.n_bar, a*b*2)} % !!!Error!!!
end
% ... Function body of MyFunc goes here ...
```

I would like to add a constraint on `options.n_bar` based on the values of `a` and `b`, such that `options.n_bar <= a*b*2`. I tried to achieve that as shown in the above code snippet, but MATLAB didn't allow me to do that in this way. How can I make it work?

Comment: Maybe worth noting (since the tag asks you to note your MATLAB release) that this syntax has only existed since R2019b ([I think](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arguments.html)). There are plenty of pre-existing ways to do this without an `arguments` block, like using the `validateattributes` function

Comment: Any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only things allowed inside of validator function calls in arguments blocks are constant expressions like `"string"` or `123`, or previously declared arguments.

This clarifies the dependencies between input arguments. This use case is a good candidate for a custom validator function.

```matlab
function MyFunc(a, b, options)
    arguments
        a (1,1) {mustBeInteger, mustBePositive}
        b (1,1) {mustBeInteger, mustBePositive}
        options.n_bar (1,1) {myMustBeLessThanOrEqual(options.n_bar, a, b)}
    end
end
function myMustBeLessThanOrEqual(w, x, y)
    mustBeLessThanOrEqual(w, x*y*2);
end
```

The above custom validator `myMustBeLessThanOrEqual` contains supported expressions, and inside the custom validator any custom logic for validation can be used.